# NIFI LIVYSESSION CONTROLLER SERVICE GIVING ERROR : READ TIMEOUT

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, livy

I want to submit spark jobs from NIFI using Executivespark interactive processor, for that I am setting up livysession controller service.
The ip and port names are correct, when I try to connect it's throwing error as shown in the attachment can anyone help me configure the controller service ?

ERROR: Timeout connecting to Livy Service to retrieve sessions:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read Time Out

[LivySessionControllerService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRxUf.png)

Comment: What version of NiFi and Livy are you using? Are you able to connect directly to the Livy REST API (through something like curl)?

Comment: Nifi Version 1.9, Haven't tested Livy via Rest API, does it has something to do with kerberos